# Runner.app/Runner.app/... infinite cycle Xcode build failed

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter, build

When I try to build my app, I got this error in the console:

```
Xcode build done.                                           114,3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    error: '/Users/paul/AndroidStudioProjects/Chronopsi/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app' is longer than filepath buffer size (1025). (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
```

I'm on Xcode 11.3.1

I have the latest version of Flutter.

I tried to build an other old app that I already build months ago and it works fine.

EDIT:
I tried to change build to legacy but I got the same error and it's still saying "note: Using new build system" while in my log it's saying "Legacy build system detected"...

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Legacy build system detected, removing /Users/paul/AndroidStudioProjects/Chronopsi/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           57,2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    error: '/Users/paul/AndroidStudioProjects/Chronopsi/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner' is longer than filepath buffer size (1025). (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
```

Comment: Is Runner in  Xcode  Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources?

Comment: yes, do I remove it?

Comment: Yah, it should solve it

Comment: it worked, thanks :) (for those with the same issue also don't forget to run flutter clean after)

Comment: @Nuts I let you write the answer if you want the bounty ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your Xcode: Targets Runner ->  Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.

If **Runner** is in the list, remove it and do `flutter clean`

[image]